# Is it possible to apply GCS-style image transformations on Firebase Storage image urls?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

It is my understanding that Firebase Storage is built on Google Cloud Storage. As such, is it possible to apply GCS-style image transformations on Firebase Storage image urls?

For example, is it possible to perform the following:

**Resize the image to 32 pixels (aspect-ratio preserved):**

`http://lhx.ggpht.com/randomStringImageId`

**To:**

`http://lhx.ggpht.com/randomStringImageId=s32`

*Code/Documentation Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is 100% possible to use the Google App Engine `get_serving_url()` call, though you'll have to set up an endpoint in GAE to do so.

If you want a backendless solution, I recommend checking out [Firebase Storage - URL for image services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700020/firebase-storage-url-for-image-services/37706262#37706262) which shows how to use Cloudinary or Imgix for these transformations.

Comment: does that mean App Engine will point to the same Google Cloud Storage (like a bucket in s3?) that firebase is pointing to, or would you have to create a whole new cloud storage instance in app engine?

Comment: Firebase uses the default GAE bucket, so you shouldn't have to create a new bucket, you can just use the existing App Engine app/bucket.